# How to create a new DB2 instance in DB2Express-C edition 10.1 using IBMDataStudio?

Tags: db2

I need to create a new DB2 instance and import a database from the earlier version of DB2, please let me know how to create a new DB2 instance, I don't want to use the default DB2 instance as my requirement is we need to crate one new DB2 instance for each release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[db2icrt](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002057.html) - Create instance command